# Permission denied error from loader on Windows

Tags: c, compiler-errors, output

I have been getting this error for the past few weeks while programming in C. I'm confused on how to fix this since the error doesn't tell me where the error is coming from. Why can the compiler not open the output file?  [image]

Comment: It doesn't have run permission, and I assume this is on windows

Comment: Just kill the process generated from your program (`bonus.exe`) and rerun.

Comment: the error tells you what the problem is..also if this is your program, then run it in debug mode, set breakpoints, and step thru the code..

Comment: You should post text and not an image if possible because text can be searched by other people looking for a similar problem, images can't.

Comment: To clarify @coderredoc's insightful recommendation, Windows will not let one process modify a file that another has open, even if both processes belong to the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Your bonus.exe file is busy due to some reason. Create a new project and try. Seems like you are working on Visual Studio. Close the application and reload also can fix your issue. This is not compilation issue rather build and link issue while it try to create bonux.exe second time it failed because your previous bonus.exe file is still busy. Also go to task manager and try to kill bonus.exe. That will also fix your issue.